# Atom or Cell? Which is the basic unit of life?

Tags: cell-biology, life

As it is said that everything in this universe is made up of atom and molecules and atoms is called the building block of matter. But then why the cell is called the basic unit of life, why not atoms?

Comment: What do you think distinguishes "life" from "not life"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a misunderstanding of the term *unit* as used in *unit of life. Unit* here refers to the smallest building block that is somewhat complete and operational in the relevant context (here: life).

Cells are called the units of life because all life we know is composed of cells. (There are some borderline cases like viruses, but even those rather resemble a cell than an atom.) On the other hand, if you cut a cell in half, it is certainly not operational or alive anymore.

You wouldn’t call atoms units of currency, even though all coins and bank notes are made up of atoms (ignoring digital currency for the sake of the analogue).